# undefined reference

Tags: c++, g++

my program is simple. a class of a bank account. Each account has a balance and an ower. each account has the same interest rate. I got the error when compile it. What's wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
  2 #include <iostream>
  3 #include <string>
  4 using namespace std;
  5 class bank
  6 {
  7 private:
  8         double balance;
  9         string owner;
 10         static double InterestRate;
 11 public:
 12         static void AccountInfo(const bank& ac)
 13         {
 14                 cout << "name: " << ac.owner << endl << "balance: " << ac.balance;
 15         }
 16         static void SetAccount(bank& ac)
 17         {
 18                 cout << "enter a name: " << flush;
 19                 cin >> ac.owner;
 20                 cout << "enter a balance: " << flush;
 21                 cin >> ac.balance;
 22         }
 23         static void SetRate(const double& n)
 24         {
 25                 InterestRate = n;
 26         }
 27         static void Balance(bank& ac)
 28         {
 29                 ac.balance += ac.balance * InterestRate;
 30         }
 31 };
 32 int main ()
 33 {
 34         bank NewAccount;
 35         bank::SetAccount(NewAccount);
 36         bank::SetRate(0.15);
 37         bank::Balance(NewAccount);
 38         bank::AccountInfo(NewAccount);
 39 return 0;
 40 }
```

and the output is:

```
  /tmp/ccUh8Sd9.o: In function `bank::SetRate(double const&)':
    e1237.cpp:(.text._ZN4bank7SetRateERKd[bank::SetRate(double const&)]+0x12): undefined reference to `bank::InterestRate'
    /tmp/ccUh8Sd9.o: In function `bank::Balance(bank&)':
    e1237.cpp:(.text._ZN4bank7BalanceERS_[bank::Balance(bank&)]+0x1c): undefined reference to `bank::InterestRate'
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Why are all functions static, and take an implicit first argument of type bank?

Comment: Regardless of the errors your design is very weird.

Comment: +1 for an complete program that actually demonstrates the error you are having. Next time, please don't put line numbers in it.

Comment: +1 to Rob: I'm sure somewhere someone has a post *how to remove all line numbers from source code examples* ... hehe

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just declared the static member `InterestRate` in your class definition but,
You also need to define your static member in one of your cpp file:

```
double bank::InterestRate = 0.0;
```

Without this the linker cannot find its definition and gives the linking error.

Comment: ahh.. Thanks. I forgot. always need to define a static member

Answer (score 3):

this happens because the line:

```
static double InterestRate;
```

is a declaration not a definition - i.e. it doesn't create a variable, but merely indicates that such a variable exists. This is very counter-intuitive in C++, but you can deal with it :-)

Add in any C++ file:

```
double bank::InterestRate;
```

to define this variable.

Ideally, if you split your project into .cpp anad .h files, you should have it in the corresponding .cpp file, while the class declaration is in .h.

Comment: is it possible to define a static data member this way? `static double InterestRate = 0.0`

Comment: Nope, initial values must go into the definition not declaration. However, for `static const` you can do like this and omit the definition outside the class.

Comment: The reason for all that fuss is the old, two-phase compilation model of C++. All modules which use that static field must know the field declaration (inside class definition), but only one module must actually create the variable so that it won't be created separately in every module that uses it. Hence static variables and global variables (same thing actually) need to be split into declaration and definition. (Constant static fields may be duplicated since they don't change, so the language provides a shorthand.)

Comment: @Kos: You can only initialise a `static const` in the declaration if it's an integer, and you can only omit the definition if nothing needs its address.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want to do is this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class bank
{
    private:
            static double InterestRate;

            double balance;
            string owner;

    public:
            void AccountInfo()
            {
                    cout << "name: " << owner << endl;
                    cout << "balance: " << balance << endl;
            }
            void SetAccount()
            {
                    cout << "enter a name: " << flush;
                    cin >> owner;
                    cout << "enter a balance: " << flush;
                    cin >> balance;
            }
            static void SetRate(const double& n)
            {
                    InterestRate = n;
            }
            void Balance()
            {
                    balance += balance * InterestRate;
            }
};

double bank::InterestRate=0;

int main ()
{
    bank NewAccount;

    bank::SetRate(0.15);
    NewAccount.SetAccount();
    NewAccount.Balance();
    NewAccount.AccountInfo();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm still not sure why you used static in the first place, but static members are used for stuff that relates to the class as such, and not to an instance. You're creating an account class (hint: better call this class Account), and now you're creating an instance of this class that most probably won't share its data with other accounts!

As a sidenote, bank accounts usually don't all have the same interest rate, so event that property should not be static. I suggest adding a `static double defaultInterest` member to the class, and a `double interest` instance variable to each account, which is assigned the default interest rate by default, but can be tweaked to contain a different interest rate for VIP customers ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Guess you must have

double bank::InterestRate = 0.;

in your C file outside of the class declaration